# where can I find vim editor key list?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I am currently using vim editor and want to customize my keys

I have learned how to map certain keys to keys by searching documentations,

but failed to find how the special keys are defined in vim.

for example, I have to use `map <Esc> <CR>` instead of `map esc enter`

I want to change ctrl key to caps lock key, but cannot find how that special keys are represented in vim editor.

Also want to change :w to something.

failed to find recommended documentations, some advice would be appreciated!

Comment: There are some things a terminal environment can't handle. Consider mapping some of these at the OS level. (e.g., using `xmodmap`.)

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn Vim sufficiently before trying to change mappings (except for ctrl/caps one, that one makes sense and doesn't conflict with anything). However, specifically caps lock cannot be detected by Vim - look for your OS or third party software for that. The way to do it is different for each OS though, so you should tag appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all special Key notations by entering `:h key-notation`. `:h key-codes` or `:h keycodes`.

But Vim will not receive the press of a key Like `Capslock` or `Ctrl` (Modifiers). The OS does not pass it to vim. Vim will only know about `Ctrl` the moment a second key is pressed, and receive the result of them both: `Ctrl+p` for example is one keypress for vim.

It is the same with Capslock. Vim will just receive the modified Character. So if Capslock is on and you press `a` vim will not receive `Capslock+a` but only `A` because that is the result of both.